# Change Spinner adapter OnItemSelectedListener arguments

Tags: android, arguments, parameter-passing, spinner, adapter

Hy,

Is there a way to change the arguments set od the OnItemSelectedListener() method?
So instead of that:

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    }
```

Something like that:

```
@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id, String myString) {
        }
```

Essentially I'd like to send a String from my adapter to my activity.
So is there a way?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
So in this fragment I have an array of String, and I'd like to get the one corresponding to the position I clicked in my spinner.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_createitem, container, false);

        currentDate.setTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

        title = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Title);
        date = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Date);
        date.setText(buildDateText(currentDate));
        date.setOnClickListener(this);
        calIMG = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.CalIMG);
        calIMG.setOnClickListener(this);
        value = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.Value);
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.Image);
        image.setOnClickListener(this);

        mySpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(new MySpinnerAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), icons));
        mySpinner.setSelection(0, false);
        mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
.
.
.
```

Comment: No, there is no way, but you don't need to. where are you defining your adapter?

Comment: Updated my question